# Button enable and disable on text changed event

Tags: c#, winforms

I am wondering how I can set a button to disable if there is no text inside a text box, but when there is re enable it? Would I put it into a text changed event?

Comment: APS.NET or WPF or WinForm?

Comment: winform, sorry I am new to programming

Comment: But you're not new in this site, please tag properly to help others help you better.

Comment: I have only used the site a few times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that (WinForms):

```
private void myTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  myButton.Enabled = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(myTextBox.Text);       
}
```

**EDIT**: For *initial form load* you can use `Load` event:

```
private void myForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  myButton.Enabled = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(myTextBox.Text); 
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly, although when the form is fist opened and no text has been entered it of course won't work, do you know how to fix that?

Comment: @Jeremy M: for initial load you can use `Load` event of the form

Comment: Uhhhh I am terribly stupid :(. Thanks though, I will upvote your comment when possible.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this?

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
    button1.Enabled = true;
else
    button1.Enabled = false;
```

Don't forget that you can change the default property of that button.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a more structured way using data binding and the little helper from here [Exchange UserControls on a Form with data-binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32974894/exchange-usercontrols-on-a-form-with-data-binding/32979774#32979774)

```
static void Bind(Control target, string targetProperty, object source, string sourceProperty, Func<object, object> expression)
{
    var binding = new Binding(targetProperty, source, sourceProperty, true, DataSourceUpdateMode.Never);
    binding.Format += (sender, e) => e.Value = expression(e.Value);
    target.DataBindings.Add(binding);
}
```

Note that this is reusable piece of code that you can use in many scenarios. For your particular case, all you need is (after copying the code above) to put the following line in your form load event:

```
Bind(button1, "Enabled", textBox1, "Text", value => !string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)value));
```